# What is the purpose of Imposteriser?

Tags: junit, jmock

I'm following this tutorial: http://jeantessier.com/SoftwareEngineering/Mocking.html#jMock

I am trying to mock a class.

I don't understand what the Imposteriser does? http://www.jmock.org/javadoc/2.5.1/org/jmock/api/Imposteriser.html

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is described in the [MockObjectTestCase JavaDoc](http://jmock.org/javadoc/jmock-2.6.0/doc/org/jmock/Mockery.html#setImposteriser%28org.jmock.api.Imposteriser%29). Essentially an Imposteriser is a strategy for creating mock objects.

By default, `MockObjectTestCase` will only allow you to create mocks for interfaces, not classes. If you would like to mock interfaces *and* classes, you need to tell `MockObjectTestCase` to use a different strategy for creating mocks:

```
setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
```